# Сдвиг картинки влево

Tags: jquery, javascript

Привет всем.

Есть вопрос по поводу сдвига картинок. Есть блок, в нем img абсолютно спозиционирована по центру. Так вот, если картинка больше блока, то ее надо сдвинуть влево на ширину половины блока, таких блоков пусть будет 9, и у каждого картинка разной ширины. Я что-то нашел, но влево сдвигается только на определенную ширину. Как сделать, я так понял: от первого отсчитывается и присваивается всем img left:-83px;
ширина and height #good 210x220 overfllow hidden, высота img 100

```
$( "#good img" ).each( function(){

    $( this ).css(
        "left", (($('#goods').width()-g)/2)
        );
});
var g = $( "#good img" ).each(function(){
    $(this).width();
});
```

Comment: Какая-то печальная и запутанная история. У вас на странице, блок с **id = goods** в единственном экземпляре, поэтому "*таких блоков пусть будет 9*" - не катит. Если вам надо подгонять каждую картинку в своём собственном блоке, то перебирать проще не изображения, а родительские блоки, высчитывая их параметры и адаптируя дочернее изображение.

Comment: Спасибо большое, это то, что нужно
    var goods = $('.goods'),
    blockW = goods.width();
goods.each(function(i, el){
    var cImg = $('img',el),
        imgW = cImg.width();
    if(imgW != blockW){
        cImg.css('left', -(imgW - blockW) / 2);
    }
});

Нужно было, чтобы фотки, вставленные в блок, не искажались а обрезалсь либо по краям, либо по верху и по низу.
Пойду посмотрю each поподробней.

Comment: Т.е. вот эта строчка значит, что мы берем у блока .goods доп. класс b_^
el =  b1 , b2 ,b3 ...?
var cImg = $('img',el),

Comment: @zif001, нет, никаких доп. классов мы ни у кого не берем. Эти классы я создал для примера, чтоб сделать блоки разных размеров. В цикле (*each*) мы перебираем каждый из блоков, находим в текущем его дочернее изображение - $('img', el) - и устанавливаем соответствующее позиционирование.

Answer (score 1):

Исходя из предложенных вами данных, такой вариант должен работать:

```
var g;
var goodWidth = $('#goods').width();
$("#good img").each( function(){
     g = (goodWidth - $(this).width())/2;
     $(this).css("left", g);
});
```